# Is it possible to host my WordPress plugin in GitHub?

Tags: wordpress, git, github, svn, tortoisesvn

I know that the WordPress plugin directory is hosting site and not a listing site.

In order for your plugin to appear in the directory is to host your plugin with them using SVN.

I have used their SVN for a while and just wonder if I can instead use a GitHub repository and whenever I release a new version on GitHub it will automatically release an update on the WordPress sites which the plugin is installed.

I really think that if I used GitHub in hosting my plugin, it will not appear in the WordPress plugin directory? Am I right or wrong about it?

I want to use GitHub to release and at the same time, I want my plugin in the WordPress plugin directory.

I have tried so far following this tutorial: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/deploy-wordpress-plugins-with-github-using-transients/

But this is for self-hosted plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a straight way to get what you're looking for. At the root of it, you *need* to have your Plugin hosted and maintained on their SVN.

That said, there are some *Git to SVN Mirroring* options available that, while a bit convoluted to set up (and sometimes providing mixed results) should be able to handle what you need if you can bear to walk through the initial set-up.

Check out the following gist: https://gist.github.com/kasparsd/3749872.

If you set it up properly, you'll be able to effectively deal with your plugin like it's hosted on GitHub where it will mirror itself into WordPress's SVN, so it will show up in the Plugin Repository.

Unfortunately I haven't seen it even broached as an issue since what, 2015? So the odds of *native* GitHub repo integegration at this point don't seem all that high.